# What service in AWS has an api to schedule calling a REST api?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

GCP has a service called "[GCP Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler)".  I can simply call an api to schedule a REST endpoint call in 45 minutes OR can call the api to schedule a recurring call every 24 hours.

What is the AWS equivalent here?   I see a bunch of stuff with lambdas but don't really want the added complexity of needing a lamba (ie. GCP functions == lambdas and I don't need a GCP function to do what I need in GCP).  A lambda would be 1 more point of failure I do not want to really monitor.

TWO main questions

1. is there an equivalent (preferably without lambdas)?
2. if lambdas is the only way to go, what is the service to call to make sure I can feed the REST endpoint through to the lambda to call?  (I am really hoping I don't have to create a lambda PER job as that is even more work).

I am considering just using GCP's service and having it call our AWS endpoints as that may be a ton easier unless anyone knows of an AWS equivalent?

I have not tried anything yet as I can't quite find the correct API in AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no other equivalent in AWS if your endpoint cannot respond within [5s](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-api-destinations.html).
As you mentioned, you'd need a lambda to call your endpoint. This lambda can be triggered at a regular interval using [EventBridge](https://aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/). When creating the rule, you can specify a custom input (that could be your endpoint).

Answer (score 0):

Create an EventBridge [Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-rules.html) with an [API Destination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-api-destinations.html)

Comment: with 5s timeout limit...